# not populating merge field (detail link) through apex

Tags: apex

Is there any way to populate {!Opportunity.link}  while sending email through apex? or
    Is there any way to replace {!Opportunity.id} with 15 or 18 character id like:
    https://xx.salesforce.com/{!Opportunity.Id}

Below is my code: 
      I am trying replace "{!Opportunity.id} with op.id" in order to add that id to my url https://xx.salesforce.com/ in the template.

```
EmailTemplate emailTemplates = [Select Body, HtmlValue, Id, Name, Subject from EmailTemplate where Name = ' Email notification on Opportunity' Limit 1];
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> theEmails = new list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for (Opportunity op : newList) {

   list<string> emaillist = new list<string>();
   emaillist.add(bccEmail);
   string body = emailTemplates.Body;
   body = body.replace('{!Opportunity.Name} ', op.Name);
   body = body.replace('{!Opportunity.id}', op.id);

   string subject = emailTemplates.Subject;

   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
   mail.setToAddresses(emaillist);
   mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplates.Id);
   mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
   mail.setSubject(subject);
   mail.setPlainTextBody(body);

   theEmails.add(mail);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method to get the current base url of your Salesforce instance:

`system.url.getsalesforcebaseurl().toexternalform()`

So then you can do something like this:

```
String sfUrl = system.url.getsalesforcebaseurl().toexternalform();
body = body.replace('{!Opportunity.id}',sfUrl+'/'+op.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a template, you can't also set the body. Instead, use setWhatId to associate the email to the opportunity, and this should allow the merge fields to work correctly:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setToAddresses(emaillist);
mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplates.Id);
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
mail.setWhatId(op.Id);
```

Also, if possible, consider using a user ID with setTargetObjectId to minimize the "bulk email" usage limits.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId()); // Or another user you get from a query...
mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplates.Id);
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
mail.setWhatId(op.Id);
```